# Measure processor loading in Webots

Tags: webots

Is there a way to measure the CPU usage or the processor loading per simulation time step? I essentially want a way to compare the computational cost of different controller implementations

I reckon I can get an indication of CPU usage on my Mac's Activity Monitor, but was wondering if there's a better and more quantitative way

For context, I am simulating different kinds of controllers for a swarm robot system consisting of ~40 e-puck robots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `--log-performance` command line option of Webots. According to the [Webots user guide](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/starting-webots#command-line-arguments):

```
  --log-performance=<file>[,<steps>]
    Measure the performance of Webots and log it in the file specified in the
    <file> argument. The optional <steps> argument is an integer value that
    specifies how many steps are logged. If the --sysinfo option is used, the
    system information is prepended into the log file.
```

If that is not sufficient, I would recommend you to recompile Webots from the source and add your own timers inside the code of Webots.

*Disclaimer: I am a [Webots](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots) developer working at [Cyberbotics](https://cyberbotics.com).*

Comment: I can't find the log file saved anywhere, I tried `webots --mode=fast --no-rendering --stderr --stdout --minimize  --log-performance=perflog e-puck2.wbt  &> log.txt &` and also with perflog.txt... Could the redirection of terminal output to log.txt be causing any issues?

Comment: Did you try to use an absolute path instead? E.g., `webots --log-performance=/Users/username/Documents/perflog.txt`?

Comment: That made it work - thanks very much!